# c# How to get all files in a folder regardless of their file type

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve all the file paths in a specific folder location. I use the Directory.GetFiles("path of folder containing files") method, but it only detects files of type "File", and not files such as "ATC File". The files have no extentions.

Is there a way of retrieving all files regardless of their type? If possible folders (of type "File Folder") should not be detected.

I use the following code:

```
string[] filesInSelectedFolder = Directory.GetFiles(fileLocation);
```

Comment: What is a "ATC" file? `Directory.GetFiles()` has some overloads to specify a search pattern. Alternatively, you could use `Directory.GetFileSystemEntries()` and then check these files further

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.bmp",
                                     SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```